# Matrix structure with constant time insertion for columns and row

Tags: data-structures, matrix

I'm looking for a matrix structure, a two-dimensional array of sorts that allows me to insert new rows AND columns in constant time. Sort of like a two-dimensional linked list.

The reason I can't use a two dimensional linked list is because I still want to keep the table like structure.

I don't have any requirements on access but the structure must be iteratable.
Removal should also be constant time.

What I'm guessing is that this can't be done and that I'll have to iterate through all the columns when inserting a new row and all the rows when inserting a new column.

I'm asking this question just in case something like this IS possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used my own solution. I use two linked lists and a dictionary that takes a pair of linked list nodes as a key. Inserting a row and a column is O(1) because of the linked list and lookups are O(1) because of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider something like a sparse matrix.  Default/empty values are represented by the absence of an item record, and the overall matrix structure header contains the dimensions of the matrix.  Rows and columns can be *appended* very quickly, simply by increasing the structure's bounds properties.

However, if you also want to *insert* rows and columns between existing rows and columns, things get a little trickier, and you would need a combination of two lists and a two-dimensional doubly-linked list.  You won't get constant time inserts here.

Your basic structure would contain a structure containing row headers and a structure containing column headers.  With the right list implementation, inserting/deleting a row or column *header* would be O(n) (i.e. related to the number of rows/columns).  Then, each row and each column header would have a list of pointers to their data items, where they exist.  Again, using the right list implementation, inserting data should also be O(n), related to the number of items in the row and the number of items in the column.  This performance is similar to that of a list.

Comment: I've actually figured out a way to do it. I use two linked lists and a dictionary that takes a pair of linked list nodes as a key. Inserting a row and a column is O(1) because of the linked list and lookups are O(1) because of the dictionary.

Comment: *Adding* to a linked list *is* O(1), however *inserting* into the middle of a linked list is O(n).  Using a dictionary is an interesting idea.  Perhaps you could post your solution as an answer so others can benefit from it.  If my answer helped, perhaps you could upvote it.

Comment: Well, inserting into the linked list is O(1) in the sense that you don't need to move other elements when you insert. And in my situation, I always have a direct reference to the element after which I want to insert a new element.